# SQL OleDb provider string parameter - how does it work?

Tags: sql, xsd, sql-server-2000, oledb

I'm using .xsd dataset visual tool to help me build SQL DAL. Unfortunately, the server I'm connecting to is SQL Server 2000. So from VS 2010 the only provider I foud was OLE DB provider. This has some disadvantages. E.g. `?` instead of named parameters etc.

I have a problem with querying for text part. Query in designer looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE nvarcharcolumn1 LIKE '%' + ? + '%'
```

This works fine from designer, when I insert value for this `?` as `%`. `%` doesn't work and neither does `''`.

But after I use xsd "Preview Data" it doesn't work with any of these values. And when called from C# code it doesn't work either.

How can I use string parameters correctly, when I want to filter by part of string and eventually allow omission of this parameter (one possibility is to create a query for each combination of not-required parameters but it's too much redundant code IMO).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE nvarcharcolumn1 LIKE '%<part of a string you want to search>%'
```

Comment: your query would leave you WIDE-OPEN for SQL-injection

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the string setup will open you up to SQL-injection.  You should really use parameters something like

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE nvarcharcolumn1 LIKE ?", yourConnection );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "QmarkPlaceHolder", "%" + ValueLookingFor + "%" );
```

then continue execution of your query